# How to find number of trials in Binomial Distribution?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have a biased coin that we are testing that has a probability of getting a tail= 0.6. Say we test the coin. Using this information how do I find the number of trials P(X>=10)<=0.05?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for the values of $n$ such that $P(X \ge10) \le 0.05$?

Comment: What is X here ?

Comment: @Vikash B X would represent the number of heads (successes) out of n trials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting your questions as follows.

You have tossed a bias coin, with $p=0.6$, and observed 10 heads. You are interested in determining the number of trials $n$ where $P(X \ge 10) \le 0.05$

In this case, you essentially want to determine which values of $n$ will satisfy:

\begin{equation}
P(X \ge 10) = \sum_{x=10}^{n}  {n \choose x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \le 0.05
\end{equation}

We can then use R to test out different values of $n$, note that $n\ge10$ in order for this probability to be defined.

```
N = 10:15
names(N) = 10:15
prb = unlist(lapply(N, function(x){sum(dbinom(10:x, x, 0.6))}))
prb[prb <= 0.05]
prb
```

Output:

```
  10          11 
0.006046618 0.030233088
```

Setting $n$ as 10 or 11 will satisfy the above contraint.